# Write a for loop in a function to get a matrix

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, matrix

I need to put `delta.vec` and `sigma.vec` values through my `required.replicates` function and store them in my `practice1` matrix.

But I get `NULL`.

```
sigma.vec <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12)
delta.vec <- c(1,2,5,8,10)

practice1 <- matrix(0, nrow=length(delta.vec), ncol=length(sigma.vec))

required.replicates <- function(delta, sigma, z.alpha = 1.959964, z.beta=0.8416212) {
  for(i in 1:length(delta.vec)) {
    for(j in 1:length(sigma.vec))
      practice1[i,j] <- ceiling((2*(z.alpha + z.beta)^2)* (sigma[j]/delta[i])^2)
    }
  }

practice1 <- required.replicates(delta=delta.vec, sigma=sigma.vec)
practice1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more efficient:

```
required.replicates <- function (delta, sigma, z.alpha, z.beta) {
 oo <- 1 / outer(delta, sigma, "/")
 ceiling(oo ^ 2 * 2 * (z.alpha + z.beta) ^ 2)
 }

practice1 <- required.replicates(delta.vec, sigma.vec, 1.959964, 0.8416212)
```

---

Fix to your original code

```
required.replicates <- function(delta, sigma, z.alpha = 1.959964, z.beta=0.8416212) { 
 oo <- matrix(0, nrow=length(delta), ncol=length(sigma))
 for(i in 1:length(delta)) 
  for(j in 1:length(sigma))
   oo[i,j] <- ceiling((2*(z.alpha + z.beta)^2)* (sigma[j]/delta[i])^2)
 return(oo)
 }

practice1 <- required.replicates(delta.vec, sigma.vec, 1.959964, 0.8416212)
```

> Thanks! One more question, if I want any value in the matrix less than 3 to have a value of 3 and any value more than a 1000 to return as NA what additions should I make?

```
practice1[practice1 < 3] <- 3
practice1[practice1 > 1000] <- NA
practice1
```

Comment: Thanks!  One more question, if I want any value in the matrix less than 3 to have a value of 3 and any value more than a 1000 to return as NA what additions should I make?

Comment: Awesome!  Apparently, I need to put that info in my function with an "if " statement.  How would that look?

Comment: I understand your answer.  I just need the if statement as requirement for the assignment.